# Determining how and which inequalities are homogeneous?

Tags: inequality

I know that if you get an inequality which is homogeneous, you can make certain assumptions without loss of generality, but my question is, how exactly do you know if an inequality is homogeneous or not? Fir example, say we have $$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$ How do we determine if this inequality is homogeneous or not?

Comment: For your case, letting $f(a, b) := \frac{a+b}{2} - \sqrt{ab}$, we have $f(t a, tb) = tf(a,b)$ for all $t > 0$, so it is homogeneous. In general, check if $f(tx) = t^p f(t)$ for all $t > 0$, where $p$ is some real number.